# Pandas Dataframe replace NaN values of column A with values from column B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following DataFrame that i got after left merging two dfs:

| A | B | C_x | D_x | C_y | D_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1136006640 | NaT | NaT | 2022-11-18 | 2022-11-24 |
| 1 | 1136030941 | NaT | NaT | 2022-11-30 | 2022-12-09 |
| 3 | 1136051543 | 2022-11-25 | 2022-12-16 | NaT | NaT |
| 4 | 1136072241 | NaT | NaT | 2022-12-20 | 2022-12-29 |

How can I join the C and D columns, so that the NaT values are replaced by the date. If the _x columns has data, the _y column is always NaT and vice versa. Can I fix this already, when merging or do i have to do it afterwards?

Comment: df.loc[df['C_x'].isna(), 'C_x'] = df['C_y']

Comment: How do your two initial DataFrames look like and which merge command did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below constructs new columns `C_z`,`D_z`. To this end, it copies dates from columns `C_y`, `D_y`. If there are no dates for a specific row in both columns, it copies dates from `C_x`,`D_x`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO
    
# setup sample data
data = """  
A;B;C_x;D_x;C_y;D_y
0;1136006640;NaT;NaT;2022-11-18;2022-11-24
1;1136030941;NaT;NaT;2022-11-30;2022-12-09
3;1136051543;2022-11-25;2022-12-16;NaT;NaT
4;1136072241;NaT;NaT;2022-12-20;2022-12-29
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';', parse_dates=['C_x','D_x','C_y','D_y'])

# copy `C_y`,`D_y`
df[['C_z','D_z']] = df[['C_y','D_y']]

# combine dates
mask = df[['C_y','D_y']].isnull().all(axis=1)
df.loc[mask,'C_z'] = df['C_x']
df.loc[mask,'D_z'] = df['D_x']
```

Result:

```
   A           B        C_x        D_x        C_y        D_y        C_z        D_z
0  0  1136006640        NaT        NaT 2022-11-18 2022-11-24 2022-11-18 2022-11-24
1  1  1136030941        NaT        NaT 2022-11-30 2022-12-09 2022-11-30 2022-12-09
2  3  1136051543 2022-11-25 2022-12-16        NaT        NaT 2022-11-25 2022-12-16
3  4  1136072241        NaT        NaT 2022-12-20 2022-12-29 2022-12-20 2022-12-29
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with remove suffixes for same columns names:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='_x$').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_x',''))
df2 = df.filter(regex='_y$').rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_y',''))

df = df.join(df1.combine_first(df2))
print (df)
   A           B        C_x        D_x        C_y        D_y          C  \
0  0  1136006640        NaT        NaT 2022-11-18 2022-11-24 2022-11-18   
1  1  1136030941        NaT        NaT 2022-11-30 2022-12-09 2022-11-30   
2  3  1136051543 2022-11-25 2022-12-16        NaT        NaT 2022-11-25   
3  4  1136072241        NaT        NaT 2022-12-20 2022-12-29 2022-12-20   

           D  
0 2022-11-24  
1 2022-12-09  
2 2022-12-16  
3 2022-12-29
```

If input data are like:

```
print (df1)
            B          C          D
0  1136051543 2022-11-25 2022-12-16

print (df2)
            B          C          D
0  1136006640 2022-11-18 2022-11-24
1  1136030941 2022-11-30 2022-12-09
2  1136072241 2022-12-20 2022-12-29
```

Then instead `merge` use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) (if `df1.index` not exist in `df2.index`, so `merge` create missing values like in question):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('B', ignore_index=True)
print (df)
            B          C          D
0  1136006640 2022-11-18 2022-11-24
1  1136030941 2022-11-30 2022-12-09
2  1136051543 2022-11-25 2022-12-16
3  1136072241 2022-12-20 2022-12-29
```